# azure recovery services notifications

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I have recently set up Microsoft Azure Backup to protect Windows Servers under recovery services.  I know that you can setup retention schedules and back up schedules via the local GUI and powershell but **does anyone know of a way to have Azure send email notifications of successful and/or failed backups through this service.**
All of the servers are local and not Azure VMs.

Answer (score 0):

Last section in the article. Should allow you to get emails for your Azure Protect jobs (yes, i'm calling it azure protect, and I wish MS would to - Azure Backup is a whole different product, and combine that with Classic/ARM, and it is nigh impossible to find the right information)

Seems to be the only way. I'm sure MS will have a feature implemented eventually.

```
PS C:\> $actionEmail = New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -CustomEmail contoso@microsoft.com
PS C:\> Add-AzureRmLogAlertRule -Name backupFailedAlert -Location "East US" -ResourceGroup RecoveryServices-DP2RCXUGWS3MLJF4LKPI3A3OMJ2DI4SRJK6HIJH22HFIHZVVELRQ-East-US -OperationName Microsoft.Backup/backupVault/Backup -Status Failed -TargetResourceId /subscriptions/86eeac34-eth9a-4de3-84db-7a27d121967e/resourceGroups/RecoveryServices-DP2RCXUGWS3MLJF4LKPI3A3OMJ2DI4SRJK6HIJH22HFIHZVVELRQ-East-US/providers/microsoft.backupbvtd2/BackupVault/trinadhVault -Actions $actionEmail
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-manage-vms-classic/